# Cannot produce document with xcookybooky

Tags: errors, header-footer, compiling, xcookybooky

I am trying to create my own cookbook, using package `xcookybooky`. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % for creating the lines for the hint
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[clock, misc, weather]{ifsym} % Symbolpackage e.g. \Interval, \Wecker etc
\usepackage{cookingsymbols} % Cookings symbols e.g. \Oven, \Dish etc
\usepackage{emerald} % Handwritten Fonts
\usepackage{wrapfig} % To wrap the tabular with the ingredients
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{lettrine} % numbering the preparation steps
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{eso-pic} % for background pictures
\usepackage{picture} % for modfifying the position of the bg pictures
\usepackage{tabularx} % line breaks in tabular
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}
        [
preparationtime = 30 min,
bakingtime = 1 hour,
bakingtemperature = \unit[225]{C},
portion = 4 portions,
calory = 4 kj,
source = My neighbour Sarah
]{Currywurst}
        \graph{
small = strawberry,
smallpicturewidth = 0.3\textwidth,
big = strawberrycake,
bigpicturewidth = 0.6\textwidth,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ingredients{
2 Tafeln & dunkle Schokolade (über \unit[70]{\%})\\
3 & Eier\\
\unit[200]{ml} & Sahne\\
\unit[40]{g} & Zucker\\
\unit[50]{g} & Butter
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\preparation{
\step This is the first step for cooking a brilliant meal.
\step The second step follows...
\step and so on
\step Enjoy your meal!
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setRecipeLengths{
preparationwidth = 0.60\textwidth,
ingredientswidth = 0.35\textwidth,
pictureheight = 6cm,
bigpicturewidth = 0.6\textwidth,
smallpicturewidth = 0.35\textwidth
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setRecipeSizes{
recipename = \fontsize{25pt}{30pt},
ing = \normalsize,
inghead = \normalsize,
prep = \normalsize,
prephead = \normalsize,
hint = \normalsize,
hinthead = \Large
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setRecipenameFont{
%pbsi
%fau
%fwb
%fjd % default when using the option handwritten
cmr % default
}{T1}{m}{n}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setHeadlines{
inghead = Ingredients,
prephead = Preparation,
hinthead = Hint,
calory = energy content,
continuationhead = Continuation,
continuationfoot = Continuation on next page
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setBackgroundPicture
[%
x = 2cm,
y = -1cm,
width=\paperwidth-3cm,
height,
orientation=pagecenter
]{pic/bg_transparent} % filepath
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it I get 4 errors and no produced output. The following code lines, are from the log.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+ cmr  on input line 95.
(C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex-ewd\t1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \headline
             {\bf \title}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! I can't find file `dotnot{'.
<to be read again> 
                   protect 
l.5 \headline{\bf
                  \title}
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   protect 
l.5 \headline{\bf
                  \title}
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

I see that there is something going on with `T1` fonts but I don't know what. If I remove the relevant line from the document, the errors are 104...

There is also an error that has to do with `dotnot` but the package `cookingsymbols` seems to be working fine.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Please reduce your example.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thank you very much for your comment! If I remove any  part of the code I get a lot of errors(104) that I won't be able to  produce them to you.

Comment: Work from this https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/7171965 (which produces http://i.stack.imgur.com/qR4Ui.png)  Note that `\unit[225]{C}` needs to be wrapped in braces since it is a keyval argument.

Comment: Remove the spaces before and after `cmr` in: `\setRecipenameFont{cmr}{T1}{m}{n}`.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Thank you very much for your comment! The wrapped `\unit[225]{C}` rwas really faulty! Thank's!!!

Comment: @Robert: Thank you for your comment! That was what making the real damage! Thank you!!! Now it's working, however I see that in the preperation environment, the numbers are not well aligned with the steps.

Comment: What do you mean by *not well aligned*? If the step is longer, the number is printed as `lettrine`.

Comment: By the way, your recipe is strange. It show a strawberry, and uses chocolate to get Currywurst. Seems like you confused something there, if not, i'd like to taste it ;-)

Comment: @SeanAllred Can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As per @SeanAllred comment: `\unit[225]{C}` needs to be wrapped in braces since it is a keyval argument:

```
[...]
bakingtemperature = {\unit[225]{C}},
[...]
```